# git-tf clone to DevOps

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfvc, git-tf

I'm trying to use git-tf to migrate some old TFVC projects from our local TFS to AzureDevOps (also a project with TFVC).

git-tf clone ... works
No I have the folder e.g. C:\TFSMigration\ProjectX

When I do git-tf checkin --deep the sourcecode is checked in in DevOps correctly but all files are in the parent-repository not in $DevOpsProjectWithTFVC/ProjectX

Here is my config:

> collection = https://myCompany.visualstudio.com
>
> serverpath = $/DevOpsProjectWithTFVC

Comment: First of all, use `git-tfs` tool and not `git-tf`.

Comment: No sorry thats not right. As I asked it here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58609968/clone-git-to-tfs-azuredevops-with-git-tfs?noredirect=1#comment103541664_58609968) I want to Migrate TFVC -> DevOps(TFVC). And this is not possible as Philippe said.

Comment: Indeed you cannot use a Git migratory tool to transfer TFVC repository, you can go from TFVC to git (with history), git to git (clone) but not TFVC to TFVC with history, you can take the tip (latest version) and checkin to the other server or project though.

Answer (score 0):

For this to work, you need a clean git clone of you original TFVC. Do the following:

1. `git-tf clone <TFVC> <Branch> --deep` from the original TFVC to a local git repo.
2. `git clone <Local git repo>` the local repo to a new folder in your local computer.
3. `git-tf configure <Destine TFVC> --deep` (Execute this inside the new folder cloned from the git repo)
4. `git-tf checkin`

The first clone you execute using git-tf is mapped to the original TFVC so you won't be able to push the changes from there.